# Clearing all selected items in _SelectionChanged()

Tags: windows-phone-7, listbox

I have a multi-select ListBox and I try to deselect all items like this:

```
private void _SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)  {

    foreach(var i in e.AddedItems) {
        // do whatever - works ok
    }

   //then clear all selected - doesn't work
   ((ListBox)(e.OriginalSource)).SelectedItems.Clear(); 

}
```

I have tried `(e.OriginalSource as Listbox).SelectedItems.Clear()` as well, but it just throws an error.

Any advice would be appreciated, thanks.

EDIT:

After many tries this works:

```
((ListBox)sender).SelectedItem = null;
```

regardless of the fact that it is multi- not single- select ListBox!

Answer (score 0):

The following is what you were actually looking for:

```
((ListBox)sender).SelectedItems.Clear();
```

The reason calling `.SelectedItem = null` works is just the behavior of the ListBox. Both end up doing the same thing. The more "correct" one is the line I gave you.